# Remove Comment Author Link only for subscribers

Tags: filters, comments, author, links

I am using this function

```
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_link', 'remove_comment_author_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_comment_author_link( $return, $author, $comment_ID ) {
   return $author;
}
```

to remove the users profile link from comments of a post.

I have been trying to use this filter but for removing the link only from subcribers users and not from everybody.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't feel very nice since it calls get_comment() and get_userdata(), but I'm not sure there's an obvious better way since the code that calls this doesn't pass in the records we need:

```
function remove_comment_author_link( $return, $author, $comment_ID ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );

    if ( $comment && $comment->user_id ) {
        $user = get_userdata( $comment->user_id );

        if ( $user && $user->has_cap( "edit_posts" ) ) {
            // This user is contributor or better: show author link
            return $return;
        }
    }

    // Subscriber or not a blog user
    return $author;
}
```

and other functions have already made the exact same lookups and so the values will already be in wp_cache_get() for this page load.

I'm also using "edit_posts" to test if a user is better than subscriber: there may be better ways to do this too. (And I'm surprised we don't have to HTML-escape $author, but the existing get_author_comment_link() code doesn't.)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Rup . It worked like a charm!!